# Responsive Site not working on iPhone

Tags: css

Not sure why, but my site here is:
http://soforealmusic.com/

I built out some responsive css and everything seems ok on my computer. But when I view it on my phone, it screws up.

Any idea what's up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding this in your HTML `<head>` tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding this in your HTML  tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```